# Create matrix of instances in veriloga

Tags: verilog

Is it possible do create an crossbararray of memristormodules with two for loops in veriloga? I have the following code but it does not work:

```
module variable_crossbar(I, V);

`define size 4

output [`size:1] I;
electrical [`size:1] I;
input [`size:1] V;
electrical [`size:1] V;

genvar i,j;

analog begin

for(i = 1; i < `size; i = i + 1) begin
    for(j = 1; j <= `size; j = j + 1) begin
        JART_VCM_2 mem_'j'_'i' ( V[j] , I[i] ); //memristormodulefile is included
    end
end

end
endmodule
```

Comment: I tried to write it in verilog ams using a generate block and it worked but the generate keyword works differently in veriloga from what I understand.

Comment: Im new to veriloga so I can’t answer the second question.

Comment: you said that the generate block **did work**. What is the question then?

Answer (score 0):

Verilog-A is not a standard by itself. It is described in Appendix C of the Verilog-AMS LRM (which you provided a link to).

Verilog-AMS was standardized based on the pre-existing implementation. As such, it is a set of analog extensions mixed with IEEE 1364-2004 Verilog, and a tiny bit of IEEE 1800 SystemVerilog (the `string` type). Verilog-AMS standardization was all done at Accellera. Normally Accellera standards feed into IEEE standards, but this proved to be problematic since by the time the possibility of IEEE standardization arose, IEEE 1364 Verilog was superseded by IEEE 1800 SystemVerilog. IEEE does not normally allow standards based on other superseded standards. There has been work on upgrading to SystemVerilog-AMS but this is a mammoth task and has not yet borne any fruit.

Verilog-A and Verilog-AMS should support `generate` and `genvar`.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can tell pure Verilog-A does not support instantiating modules with generate loops. Verilog-AMS, a superset language of Verilog-A, does.

Verilog-A and Verilog-AMS are frequently referred to interchangeable in my research. From what I can tell, the original Verilog-A was derived from Verilog (IEEE1364-1995) syntax; adding analog features (Ex: `electrical`, `V()`, etc.) and removing digital features (`reg`, `always`, etc.). The latest version of Verilog-AMS merged Verilog (IEEE1364-2005) with Verilog-A, supporting both syntax and features in one language. Oddly, Verilog-AMS [LRM](https://www.accellera.org/images/downloads/standards/v-ams/VAMS-LRM-2-4.pdf) explicitly refers to IEEE1364-2005, buts does not mention Verilog-A despite using the same analog syntax. Maybe they are near identical competing languages, or maybe there is some trademark issue over the names, or some other convoluted reason I couldn't figure out in the time I allocated to look up Verilog-A and Verilog-AMS.

---

With Verilog-AMS you can use the Verilog approach to instantiating modules with generate loops. Note the you cannot use the index in the instance name. It is recommenced to name the generate blocks (`loop_i`,`loop_j` in this example). Also not it is recommened to use `parameter` instead of  `` `define `` to prevent polluting the global space.

```
module variable_crossbar(I, V);

parameter SIZE 4; // `define are global space and assigned by compile order

output [SIZE:1] I;
electrical [SIZE:1] I;
input [SIZE:1] V;
electrical [SIZE:1] V;

genvar i,j;
generate
  for(i = 1; i < SIZE; i = i + 1) begin : loop_i
    for(j = 1; j <= SIZE; j = j + 1) begin : loop_j
      JART_VCM_2 mem ( V[j] , I[i] ); //memristormodulefile is included
    end
  end
endgenerate
endmodule
```

Again, from what I can tell pure Verilog-A does not support instantiating modules with generate loops. So hopefully what you really mean is Verilog-AMS. And hopefully your simulator supports the the features.